# I want To Rearrange My Array Same As Other Array , This Array is Key And Value

Tags: javascript

I have array 1 is Setting Array and Array 2 is Data Array.
    Now , Array 2 date and Withdrawals is Swap..! In Future will Be Other Field  is Swappable.

But Array 1 is Fix Value And Arrange Array 2 same as Array 1 Always. With Key And Value.

Array 1 :

```
{ date: 'Date',
  withdrawals: 'Withdrawals',
  deposits: 'Deposits',
  Payee: 'Payee',
  Description: 'Description',
  ReferenceNumber: 'Reference Number' }
```

Fileds Array

Array 2 :

```
[ { date: 'Withdrawals',
    withdrawals: 'Date',
    deposits: 'Deposits',
    Payee: 'name',
    Description: 'Description',
    ReferenceNumber: 'Reference Number' },
    { date: '0',
    withdrawals: '28/11/13',
    deposits: '500000',
    Payee: 'John Roberts',
    Description: 'Cheque deposit',
    ReferenceNumber: 'Ref-1900' },
  { date: '75',
    withdrawals: '22/11/13',
    deposits: '0',
    Payee: 'Smith123',
    Description: 'Electronics purchase',
    ReferenceNumber: 'Ref-2134' },
  { date: '4000',
    withdrawals: '22/1/14',
    deposits: '0',
    Payee: 'Joseph',
    Description: 'Insurance payment',
    ReferenceNumber: 'Ref-9872' } ]
```

Rearrange Array 2 same as my Array 1

Result :

```
[ { date: 'Date',
        withdrawals: 'withdrawals',
        deposits: 'Deposits',
        Payee: 'name',
        Description: 'Description',
        ReferenceNumber: 'Reference Number' },
        { date: '28/11/13',
        withdrawals: '0',
        deposits: '500000',
        Payee: 'John Roberts',
        Description: 'Cheque deposit',
        ReferenceNumber: 'Ref-1900' },
      { date: '22/11/13',
        withdrawals: '75',
        deposits: '0',
        Payee: 'Smith123',
        Description: 'Electronics purchase',
        ReferenceNumber: 'Ref-2134' },
      { date: '22/1/14',
        withdrawals: '4000',
        deposits: '0',
        Payee: 'Joseph',
        Description: 'Insurance payment',
        ReferenceNumber: 'Ref-9872' } ]
```

Comment: please add a wanted result and some code you tried.

Comment: Finely , I Want Result Array...!

Comment: actually where is the difference between array 2 and result?

Comment: In result...! date and withdrawals value is change bcz array 1 have date = date and withdrawals = withdrawals

in array 1 withdrawals has date and in result withdrawals = withdrawals and date = date that is main def.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign array1 to the first element of array2:

```
array2[0] = array1
```

Comment: I don't want to concat array 1, I want rearrange My Data Also Of Array 2 same as Array 1